# Detect if ListView or CollectionView is scrolling by user

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to detect if `ListView` or `CollectionView` is scrolling by user and not from `ScrollTo` method?

I am using `ScrollTo` as the example below:

```
colViewCategories.ScrollTo(categoryItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
```

Or if i can disable Scrolled Event till `ScrollTo` Method will stop to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer.

```
bool scrollAnimationIsRaised=false;
int previousindex = 0;
private System.Timers.Timer tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();

private void InitTimer
{
    tmr.Interval = 500; //waiting 500ms after scrollTo has Stop for not having conflicts
    tmr.Elapsed += Tmr_Elapsed;
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scrollAnimationIsRaised = true;
    listview.ScrollTo(50);
}

private void ListviewItems_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
   if(scrollAnimationIsRaised)
   {
      //ScrollToEvent Is Fired
      if (e.LastVisibleItemIndex == previousindex)
          tmr.Start();
      previousindex = e.LastVisibleItemIndex;
    }
    else
    {
          //ScrollTo event has finished
    }
}

private void Tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        tmr.Stop();
        scrollAnimationIsRaised = false;
}
```