# Xamarin CollectionView detect when scrolled to bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview

From what I can research this is not possible with CollectionView, only with scrollview. You can get the scroll event and see what the vertical position is 0, but there is no way to know that you have reached the end because you don't know what the max rendered position is. IF you programmatically scroll to to the end as its displaying it will set the end as 0 and the start as your negative max so you still don't know what it is. If you try to scroll multiple times it ignores all but the last scroll attempt. If you try to scroll inside the scroll event it ignores the scroll request. I have run out of ideas.

At least with scroll view you can get the content height and the scroll view height, and the difference is your end.

Does anyone know how to do this with the collection view? It would be greatly appreciated so I don't have to rebuild all of this with the scroll view and add all the UI elements manually. 
---EDIT---
So all of the answers have the UX experience of firing when the first pixel of the last item is visible. I don't want that, because that is a completely different UX experience then when you "feel" you hit the end and would confuse users. Every chat on cell phones loads when you hit the end. This is why I explicitly asked for how to detect when you scrolled to the end, so you can get the familiar feeling.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186052/199364, compare e. LastVisibleItemIndex to your items count minus 1.

Comment: ugh this almost worked. The issue is that this fires when the first pixel of that element is on the screen. So if your finger is just kind of there and you don't actually hit the end it will fire hundreds of times.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you scroll to onappearing it resets wherever you first scoll to as the "0", So if you scroll to the end the hight will be "negative" max, and if your scroll to beginning it will be positive max. I already tried that.

Comment: When asking a question, its helpful to explain WHY you need the requested functionality. Now that in a comment on answer you've said goal is to add items incrementally, see: [How to add items incrementally while scrolling in CollectionView in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240929/how-to-add-items-incrementally-while-scrolling-in-collectionview-in-xamarin-form) Should work the same in Maui. NOTE: see how that answer sets `isLoading = true;` while the method is doing its work? That's what suppresses multiple calls.

Comment: I have a normal chat screen where I want you to be able to scroll back in  history. The problem with collection view, including the link you added, is the UX is super weird and would confuse anyone who uses it. Because In every chat, it will load the history when you hit the END and you "feel" the end push back so you can't scroll. What this does is starts the load when the first pixel of the last item becomes visible, which the user may not be wanting to actually load the next set, just looking at the last items. Which is why I want to know when I have scrolled to the end.

Comment: Well you are right that is a better UX experience, except its simply not the norm, which is the most important for UX, familiarity. It works perfect in scrollview.

Comment: Text messages, facebook chat, microsft teams, whatsapp, all hit an end when you scroll to load more. (or that is the experience) and if you are going to implement the infinite scroll scrollview is better because you can do it based on number of pixels, so the experience will be the same regardless of the size of the text. So with collection view it would be "bumbier" if its a small text vs large text

Answer (score 0):

As Steve hinted, to detect or scroll to the bottom of the `CollectionView`, you can try to judge if the e.LastVisibleItemIndex equals to your items count-1 and then ScrollTo the bottom of the `CollectionView`.

You can refer to the sample code below:

**XAML:**

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"  
               Scrolled="CollectionView_Scrolled">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 //Omitted for brevity
            </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void CollectionView_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e) 
{
     if (e.LastVisibleItemIndex == Monkeys.Count - 1)
     {

           collectionView.ScrollTo(Monkeys.Count);
               
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. Or rather it creates a really counter inuitive UX experience. It doesn't tell you when you have scrolled to the end. it tells you when you see the first pixel of the last item. So if your items have any reasonable hight, you would start loading new items long before the user was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Load additional items without interfering with smooth-scrolling of current items. This should behave similar to loading only when last item is fully visible (except that it may fetch data earlier).

- If a server request is needed, do that on background thread.
- To avoid "glitchy" scrolling, don't add to the items source until user stops scrolling.
- The Adds are done on UI thread, so that they happen in a single UI update. This avoids situation where first Add triggers a UI update, and then additional adds don't happen until the following UI update. This could cause an extra lag in user's ability to scroll and/or glitchy scrolling.

Code:

```cs
const int TickMilliseconds = 100;
const int DelayMilliseconds = 200;   // REQUIRE: DelayMillis >= TickMillis.
public ObservableCollection<MyItemType> Items;   // Bound to CollectionView.ItemsSource.
IDispatcherTimer ScrollTimer;
DateTime LastScroll;
bool isBusy;

void CollectionView_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e) 
{
    LastScroll = DateTime.Now();
    if (isBusy)
        return;
        
    if (e.LastVisibleItemIndex == Items.Count - 1)
    {
        EnsureTimerRunning();
    }
}

void EnsureTimerRunning()
{
    if (ScrollTimer == null)
    {
        ScrollTimer = Application.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        ScrollTimer.Duration = TickMilliseconds;
        ScrollTimer.Tick += (s,e) => ScrollTimerTick();
        ScrollTimer.Start();
        // OPTIONAL: Could start pre-fetching items here. To lessen delay.
    }
}

void ScrollTimerTick()
{
    if (isBusy)
        return;
        
    var now = DateTime.Now();
    if ((now - LastScroll).TotalMilliseconds > DelayMilliseconds)
    {
        // Got to last item, then user paused scrolling.
        ScrollTimer.Stop();
        ScrollTimer = null;   // Done with this.
        AddMoreItems();
    }
}

void AddMoreItems()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ... Any code that might be slow, e.g. fetch from server.
        // OR if started pre-fetch in EnsureTimerRunning, requires not-shown code to synchronize fetching with adding.
        var items = new List<MyItemType>();
        
        try {
          ...items.Add...
          ...items.Add...
        }
        finally {        
          // Get on MainThread, to add all items in a single UI update.
          MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
          {
            try {
              // Append all new items to items source.
              foreach (var item in items)
                Items.Add(item);
            }
            finally {
              isBusy = false;   // MUST do this, even if exceptions.
            }
          }
        }
    }    
}
```